# Retrieve Link ID

Tags: php

Let say we have link as following

for link as `****.com/index.php?id=4`

the `<?=$id?>` is 4

for link as `****.com/4`

the `<?=$id?>` is 4

for link as `****.com/4-keyowrd-keyword`

```
$realid = array_shift(explode("-", $id));
```

so `<?=$realid?>` is 4

**Now my question** is for link as `****.com/4/keyword-keyword`

How then get the id as 4 is there any way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually have a complete URL with the scheme included (i.e.: http://something.com and not just something.com), you can do:

```
// Search in the query string
$url = 'http://something.php/index.php?id=4';
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $queryArr);
$id = $queryArr['id'];
echo $id; // 4

// Search in the path
$url = 'http://something.com/4/keyword-keyword';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$id = basename(dirname($path));
echo $id; // 4

// Search in the path (undefined length)
$url = 'http://something.com/4/keyword-keyword/foo/bar';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
list(,$id) = explode('/', $path);
echo $id; // 4
```

If you don't the scheme there, you can just prepend it, like:

```
$url = 'http://'.$url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and explode the `\`to get your variable

Answer (score 0):

```
$realid = array_shift(explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Comment: -1 Won't work. array_shift accepts a reference, so you get a E_STRICT error right there. Also, it will always return an empty string, since REQUEST_URI starts with a slash.